# FreeSwitch - using mod_xml_curl for Dialplan

Tags: xml, freeswitch

I am using mod_xml_curl to register SIP users on FreeSwitch server. I could get user information from My-SQL database, and now I have a problem with FreeSwitch dialplan. When I make a call to another registered user, it makes hold_music sound.

It doesn't make a call to other registered user.

```
Case 1
* No mod_xml_curl for directory
* No mod_xml_curl for dialplan 
Result - It works fine, but I cannot use user information in My-SQL database.

Case 2
* using mod_xml_curl for directory
* No mod_xml_curl for Dialplan
Result - Registeration is working using My-SQL database, but call is failed.

Case 3
* using mod_xml_curl for directory
* using mod_xml_curl for Dialplan
Result - Registeration is working using My-SQL database, but call makes hold_music sound.
```

Is there any information when I use xml_curl for dialplan?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When using `xml_curl` for the dialplan what are you returning for the dialplan? If you're returning a dialplan that plays music on hold then it works.

You can enable debugging in freeswitch using the command `xml_curl debug_on` to see what dialplan the web server returned.